# Donut chart: how to flip upside down numbers?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to figure out the logic needed to map out whether or not to rotate the text on my donut labels by 180 degrees. Basically, if they appear upside down, I want to rotate them by 180 so that readability improves. And ideally this is only for the text labels that are upside down, and not for the ones that are already readable. The question then becomes how to quantify these notions for the `if` logic. I believe that `r.startAngle` in my code would fit here. Here is a snippet.

```js
var margins = {top:20, left:50, bottom:20, right:20};

var width = 300;
                var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
                var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

                var data = [
                  {value: 43, marker: 90, label: "Cash", color: '#b8cce4', neg:false},
                  {value: 91, marker: 191, label: "Bonds", color: '#95b3d7', neg:false},
                  {value: 12, marker: 26, label: "Stocks", color: '#4f81b9', neg:false},
                  {value: 7, marker: 15, label: "Securities Funds", color: '#366092', neg:false},
                  {value: 62, marker: 130, label: "Other", color: '#a6a6a6', neg:false}
                ];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width+100).attr('height', width+100);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");
/*
    graphGroup.append('image')
        .attr('x',width/2-50)
        .attr('y',width/2-50)
        .attr('width',100)
        .attr('height',100)
        .attr("xlink:href", 'china-life.png');
*/

graphGroup.append('text')
    .attr('x',width/2-41)
    .attr('y',width/2+14)
    .style('font-size','42px')
    .text('5%');

var arcs = data.map(function (obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
});
var arcsGrey = data.map(function (obj, i) {
    return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
});

var pieData = data.map(function (obj, i) {
    return [
        {value: obj.value * 0.75, arc: arcs[i], object: obj},
        {value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75, arc: arcsGrey[i], object: obj},
        {value: 100 * 0.25, arc: arcs[i], object: obj}];
});

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
    return d.value;
});

var g = graphGroup.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');
var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
    .append('g')
    .classed('textClass', true)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');


g.selectAll('path').data(function (d) {
    return pie(d);
}).enter().append('path')
    .attr('id', function (d, i) {
        if (i == 1) {
            return "Text" + d.data.object.label
        }
    })
    .attr('d', function (d) {
        return d.data.arc(d);
    }).attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      if (d.data.object.neg==false) {
        return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none' ;
      } else {
        return i == 0 ? 'red' : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none' ;
      }}).attr('class','segments');

/*
g.selectAll('.segments').attr('fill', function(d,i) {
  return d.data.object.neg==true ? 'red' : 'none';
});
*/

graphGroup.selectAll('g').each(function (d, index) {
    var el = d3.select(this);
    var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function (r, i) {
        if (i === 1) {
            var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
                startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
                endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
            });
            var lableObj = r.data.object;
            g.append('text')
                .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
                /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
                 .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
                .append("textPath")
                .attr("textLength", function (d, i) {
                    return 0;
                })
                .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
                .attr("startOffset", '5')
                .attr('font-weight','normal')
                .attr("dy", '-3em')
                .text(function(d) {
                  if (lableObj.neg==true) {
                    return '-'+lableObj.marker;
                  } else {
                    return lableObj.marker ;
                  }
                  });
        }
        if (i === 0) {
            var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
                startAngle: r.startAngle,
                endAngle: r.startAngle
            });
            var lableObj = r.data.object;
            /*gText.append('text')
                .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
                .text(lableObj.label)
                .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
                .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');*/
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

```
    if (i === 0 && r.startAngle>180){
        var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
            startAngle: r.startAngle,
            endAngle: r.startAngle)
        } else {
        var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
            startAngle: r.startAngle*Math.pi,
            endAngle: r.startAngle*Math.pi)
        var lableObj = r.data.object; }
```

Unfortunately that results in unexpected ")" after list console error.

In the snippet, the numbers: 15 and 26 are "upside-down" and should be flipped.

### Question

How do I flip text labels on a donut chart to improve readability? Is there a built-in means or is the only way to revamp my (thus far failed) logic?

Comment: Your `unexpected ")"` is due to a missing `}` at the end of `endAngle: r.startAngle*Math.pi)`

Comment: @DBS strange, the error persists, it's pretty complicated, proving hard to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not regular text elements. Those are `<textPath>` elements.

Therefore, rotating them is not the correct solution. What you have to do is getting the length of the path...

```
var thisLength = this.getTotalLength();
```

...and moving the texts, using `startOffset`, to the end of the path, like this:

```
.attr("startOffset", function(){
    return index === 2 || index === 3 ? thisLength - 22 : 5
})
```

Pay attention to the fact that here I'm simply getting the second and third elements (magic numbers, just like `22` for the padding) to change their positions: in your real code, you'll have to right a function to find the elements whose `startOffset` need to be changed, according to a basic trigonometry.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  left: 50,
  bottom: 20,
  right: 20
};

var width = 300;
var arcSize = (6 * width / 100);
var innerRadius = arcSize * 3;

var data = [{
    value: 43,
    marker: 90,
    label: "Cash",
    color: '#b8cce4',
    neg: false
  },
  {
    value: 91,
    marker: 191,
    label: "Bonds",
    color: '#95b3d7',
    neg: false
  },
  {
    value: 12,
    marker: 26,
    label: "Stocks",
    color: '#4f81b9',
    neg: false
  },
  {
    value: 7,
    marker: 15,
    label: "Securities Funds",
    color: '#366092',
    neg: false
  },
  {
    value: 62,
    marker: 130,
    label: "Other",
    color: '#a6a6a6',
    neg: false
  }
];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width + 100).attr('height', width + 100);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");
/*
    graphGroup.append('image')
        .attr('x',width/2-50)
        .attr('y',width/2-50)
        .attr('width',100)
        .attr('height',100)
        .attr("xlink:href", 'china-life.png');
*/

graphGroup.append('text')
  .attr('x', width / 2 - 41)
  .attr('y', width / 2 + 14)
  .style('font-size', '42px')
  .text('5%');

var arcs = data.map(function(obj, i) {
  return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + innerRadius).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - (width / 100) + innerRadius);
});
var arcsGrey = data.map(function(obj, i) {
  return d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(i * arcSize + (innerRadius + ((arcSize / 2) - 2))).outerRadius((i + 1) * arcSize - ((arcSize / 2)) + (innerRadius));
});

var pieData = data.map(function(obj, i) {
  return [{
      value: obj.value * 0.75,
      arc: arcs[i],
      object: obj
    },
    {
      value: (100 - obj.value) * 0.75,
      arc: arcsGrey[i],
      object: obj
    },
    {
      value: 100 * 0.25,
      arc: arcs[i],
      object: obj
    }
  ];
});

var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
  return d.value;
});

var g = graphGroup.selectAll('g').data(pieData).enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');
var gText = graphGroup.selectAll('g.textClass').data([{}]).enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('textClass', true)
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + width / 2 + ') rotate(180)');


g.selectAll('path').data(function(d) {
    return pie(d);
  }).enter().append('path')
  .attr('id', function(d, i) {
    if (i == 1) {
      return "Text" + d.data.object.label
    }
  })
  .attr('d', function(d) {
    return d.data.arc(d);
  }).attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    if (d.data.object.neg == false) {
      return i == 0 ? d.data.object.color : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
    } else {
      return i == 0 ? 'red' : i == 1 ? '#D3D3D3' : 'none';
    }
  }).attr('class', 'segments');

/*
g.selectAll('.segments').attr('fill', function(d,i) {
  return d.data.object.neg==true ? 'red' : 'none';
});
*/

graphGroup.selectAll('g').each(function(d, index) {
  var el = d3.select(this);
  var path = el.selectAll('path').each(function(r, i) {
    if (i === 1) {
      var centroid = r.data.arc.centroid({
        startAngle: r.startAngle + 0.05,
        endAngle: r.startAngle + 0.001 + 0.05
      });
      var lableObj = r.data.object;
      var thisLength = this.getTotalLength();
      g.append('text')
        .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
        .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central')
        /*.attr('transform', "translate(" + centroid[0] + "," + (centroid[1] + 10) + ") rotate(" + (180 / Math.PI * r.startAngle + 7) + ")")
         .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')*/
        .append("textPath")
        .attr("textLength", function(d, i) {
          return 0;
        })
        .attr("xlink:href", "#Text" + r.data.object.label)
        .attr("startOffset", function() {
          return index === 2 || index === 3 ? thisLength - 22 : 5
        })
        .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
        .attr("dy", '-3em')
        .text(function(d) {
          if (lableObj.neg == true) {
            return '-' + lableObj.marker;
          } else {
            return lableObj.marker;
          }
        });
    }
    if (i === 0) {
      var centroidText = r.data.arc.centroid({
        startAngle: r.startAngle,
        endAngle: r.startAngle
      });
      var lableObj = r.data.object;
      /*gText.append('text')
          .attr('font-size', ((5 * width) / 100))
          .text(lableObj.label)
          .attr('transform', "translate(" + (centroidText[0] - ((1.5 * width) / 100)) + "," + (centroidText[1] + ") rotate(" + (180) + ")"))
          .attr('dominant-baseline', 'central');*/
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```